# Themekey Rule to Present Theme on CiviEvent Page

Tags: civievent, theme

[image: ThemeKey Rules]

This is not working for loading my theme on my CiviEvent page of civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=29

What are the right ThemeKey rules to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Themekey CiviCRM](https://github.com/fuzionnz/themekey_civicrm) from Fuzion Github, it can select themes by contribution page ID or type, and event page ID or type.

Comment: That link seems to be broken currently.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSchüttler, I must have created the repo as private. Appreciate the heads-up!

Comment: Note that if you use this (excellent) module, and you're using "CiviCRM Theme" module, you'll also need to enable the "Themekey Compatibility" module as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CiviCRM Theme module to pick a different theme for admin and for public CiviCRM pages!

(EDIT) You will find the settings on the /admin/appearance page down the bottom.

Note: you may need to enable the module on the admin/modules page!

Comment: But it can not give me a different theme PER civievent page